# Ng-repeat and auto complete selection with modal window in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modal-dialog, angularjs-ng-repeat, ngtable

I'm doing an application in Angular. It is a Table one row that contain 2 column. Each column contain one select. They are empty. When the user press a button, a modal window shows up and display a grid with all the items (from json) of the first select. When the user click on one rows and press "Confirm", modal window closes filling the first select. In the meanwhile, the second select fill with the subarray of selected item.

In a few words, there are 2 select: you choose the option on the first (by a modal window) and then you choose the item of its subarray in the second select.

Then, the user can add new rows, repeating the select.

I've tried two ways to do this, and they half work. In the [FIRST CODE](http://plnkr.co/edit/CCmAF7TDsrObQL2Vku4w?p=preview) 
you can see that, after clicked on modal window, the first select fill it self (even if it is not the first , I don't know why..). And it doesn't not iterate well, because when you choose a item in new line, it modify all the other choises, and I want to prevent this.

```
      <select ng-model="selectedProduct" ng-options="a as a.nome for a in items" ng-change="selectLot(select1)">
    <option value="">-- Select Product --</option>
  </select>

  <select ng-model="selectedLot" ng-options="a as a.value for a in selectedProduct.lots" ng-change="lotSelect(select2)">
    <option value="">-- Select Lot --</option>
  </select>
```

The [SECOND CODE](http://plnkr.co/edit/gizsam8qAXuBcuOaX6BC?p=preview) works better. It iterate well. It change automatically the second item's selection well. But when I press on the modal window, the first selection doesn't automatically fill with the choosen item.

Can you help me? I can't find a solution..... Thank you so much in advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core of the issue is that if you want to have a form that edits elements in an array, you need to have separate models for each of the rows in the array. You can do this by making "selectedProduct" and "selectedLot" into objects that map the array index to the selected value for that row.

I made an updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/KSPRpbwZusjLZjChypXv) with a working example, but without looking at it here is a rundown of the changes you would need to make. You need to change your models so they reference something using the array index of the row, and also pass that index into functions that modify the row:

```
  <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($index)">OPEN!!</button>

  <select ng-model="selectedProducts[$index]" ng-options="a as a.nome for a in items" ng-change="selectLot(select1, $index)">
    <option value="">-- Select Product --</option>
  </select>

  <select ng-model="selectedLots[$index]" ng-options="a as a.value for a in selectedProducts[$index].lots" ng-change="lotSelect(select2, $index)">
    <option value="">-- Select Lot --</option>
  </select>
```

You also want to update the functions in your controller to work with the array indexes:

```
$scope.selectLot = function(data, index){
  $scope.Subarray = [];
  for(i=0; i<$scope.items.length; i++){
    if(data == $scope.items[i].id){
      $scope.Subarray[$index] = $scope.items[i].lots;
      $scope.selectedProducts[$index] = $scope.items[i];
      break;
    }
  }
  console.log($scope.Subarray);
}

$scope.lotSelect = function(id, $index) { 
  for(i=0; i<$scope.Subarray[$index].length; i++){
    if(id == $scope.Subarray[$index][i].id){ 
      $scope.selectedLots[$index] = $scope.Subarray[$index][i];
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

And the modal:

```
$scope.open = function ($index) {
  // ... 

  modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
    $scope.selectedProducts[$index] = selectedItem;
  }, function () {
    $log.info('Finestra selezione prodotto chiusa alle ore: ' + new Date());
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably shouldn't be using a SELECT if you are allowing the choice to happen in a modal popup. All you want to do is show the selected item which you can easily do in a number of different ways.  Additionally in the first example prodIsChanged(), which is what sets the subarray, is never called. An easier solution may be something like this:

```
   <div>{{mainProduct}}</div>
   <select ng-options="a as a.value for a in selectedProduct"></select>

   var myApp = myApp.controller('Cntrl', function ($scope,$watch) {  
       $scope.mainProduct = '';
       $scope.selecedProduct = '';

       $watch('mainProduct',function(old,new) {
           $scope.selectedProduct = ??? // The mainProduct has changed so set the list of sub products as necessary
       };

   }
```